# Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed an web application, which uses facebook graph api using offline_access and it was working fine before facebook's removal of access token and addition extend expiry token.
My application post message, links and upload pictures on timeline and fanpage using graph api. Posting messages and pictures is working fine, while, posting link throwing following exception
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL.

I research over facebook developer and other net stuff but no luck.

Can anybody help to find the solution.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Check your app settings – do you have the migration „Stream post URL security” enabled? If so, disable it.

Comment: This is almost certainly the problem

Comment: this does not fix the problem when facebook applies the July 2013 migration by default, i'm looking for a solution to this issue.

Comment: Where does it say they are gonna enforce that from July 2013 on? I can’t see this mentioned in the roadmap - https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate the access token using the Graph explorer app on FB?
Make sure you select your app from the select box on the top-right.
It will be selected as Graph Explorer by default.